# Request to add Symbol for Joker

Tags: feature-request, card-renderer

As There is no symbol `Joker` in Poker site. Some Game has a `five of a kind` and they have add one special Card known as `Joker`. And as per the Google and wiki search the below Card is discover.

[image]

So my request is to add below Symbol for the Joker Card.

## *

Comment: Seems like a reasonable request to me - who has the power to make such a change?

Comment: @3N1GM4 Thanks for appreciation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Short cut Key for display Joker in the question](http://meta.poker.stackexchange.com/questions/250/short-cut-key-for-display-joker-in-the-question)

Comment: @3N1GM4 actually i ask that question but the Moderator can move my question so it is display.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean, but this question and that one are duplicates, so one of them should be closed.

Comment: @3N1GM4 I deleted the question .

Comment: @3N1GM4 The design teams from StackExchange can do that.

Comment: Is there some poker variant where the Joker is used ? I'm not aware of any..

Comment: @RaduMurzea any game using wild cards - not common in public poker rooms or casinos, but definitely in home games. And Pai Gow Poker if we count that as being on topic here, despite being a pit game.

Comment: I would vote no.  No main stream poker game uses joker.