# Why can I not submit a suggested edit for this question?

Tags: feature-request, support, editing

I was looking at [this question](https://poker.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252/request-to-add-symbol-for-joker) today which could benefit from a little editing, just to make the meaning a little clearer.

However, the edit link is greyed out with the following hover text:

`Suggested edits are not allowed on non-tag-wiki posts on meta sites.`

What does this mean and why can I not suggest edits for Poker Meta questions which might need them?

Comment: I found [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87890/why-cant-i-suggest-edits-on-se-meta-sites) on Meta Stack Exchange, but it's over 3 years old and I cannot find any more recent discussion of this topic. Seems strange to me that suggested edits would not be allowed on any Meta sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I did a bit more digging and it seems that the main reasons that suggested edits are not permitted on posts in Meta sites (except on tag wikis) are:

- Users with sufficient rep (1k on a beta site I think?) can make edits without issue
- Meta sites are low traffic, so there is less need for edit suggestions, as those high rep users above can deal with whatever needs editing
- Allowing edit suggestions on Meta sites would overwhelm/annoy those with access to the review queue for these edits

Still seems strange to me to not allow it - I would have thought the Meta sites are somewhere it's just as important to have high quality questions and IMO edit suggestions are part of that. But it seems this is by design, has been debated at length and hasn't been changed, so I guess I'll just have to wait until I accrue enough rep here to make the edits directly myself.